# How to shutdown a virtual machine on ESXi5 over an ssh terminal session?

Tags: ssh, vmware-esxi, command-line-interface, remote-access

How can I shutdown a virtual machine when I am on the commandline of an ESXi5 host over ssh?

---

Sidenote:

To enable scripts on other machines to login to the ESXi without password, add the public key of the user on the other machine to the ESXi's "/etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys" if you want to login as root. If you want to login as user x add the key to "/etc/ssh/keys-x/authorized_keys".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the section 'Using the ESXi 5.0 esxcli command to power off a virtual machine' in [KB1014165](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014165) at the [VMWare Knowledge base](http://kb.vmware.com/):

> The esxcli command can be used locally or remotely to power off a virtual machine running on ESXi 5.0. For more information, see the esxcli vm Commands section of the vSphere Command-Line Interface Reference.
>
> Open a console session where the esxcli tool is available, either in the ESXi Shell, the vSphere Management Assistant (vMA), or the location where the vSphere Command-Line Interface (vCLI) is installed.
>
> Get a list of running virtual machines, identified by World ID, UUID, Display Name and path to the .vmx configuration file, using the command:
>
> ```
> esxcli vm process list
> ```
>
> Power off one of the virtual machines from the list using the command:
>
> ```
> esxcli vm process kill --type=[soft,hard,force] --world-id=WorldNumber
> ```
>
> **Note**: Three power-off methods are available. Soft is the most graceful, hard performs an immediate shutdown, and force should be used as a last resort.
>
> Repeat step 2 and validate that the virtual machine is no longer running.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Brilliant, saves the need for an additional windows machine and a lot of time in many occasions. Especially when there are shell scripts prepared to start or shutdown some of the machines we need often.

Comment: and my question is how turn on , or restart that machine or another online machin, with ssh ? .. but this is also very useful for me ... thanks

Comment: Explained in great detail here: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1038043

Comment: For some reason i get `Error: Unknown command or namespace vm process kill –t=soft –w=67909` when trying this on 6.5 embedded host even though `esxcli vm process list` works and `esxcli vm process kill -help` confirms i'm running the correct command for my system. I'm getting closer to switching to proxmox, xen or citrix for basic systems that don't benefit from enterprise licence

Answer (score 2):

You can use vim-cmd:

Here is an example (shutdown only one VM: SRV1):

```
[root@ESX1:~] vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms
Vmid   Name          File               Guest OS       Version  
1      SRV2   [NAS] SRV2/SRV2.vmx   winLonghornGuest   vmx-08
2      SRV1   [SAN] SRV1/SRV1.vmx   winLonghornGuest   vmx-08

[root@ESX1:~]  vim-cmd vmsvc/power.shutdown 2
```

You can also shutdown all host VMs:

```
/sbin/shutdown.sh && /sbin/poweroff
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/07/vmware-esxi-apagar-todas-las-vms-desde-SSH.html

Comment: This worked for me in 6.5 embedded host. Docs on both methods here https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004340