# How to start virtual machines on the commandline of a ESXi5 host?

Tags: command-line-interface, vmware-esxi

How can I start virtual machines when I am on the commandline of a ESXi5 host over ssh ?

Comment: The shutdown operation was already solved here: http://serverfault.com/questions/321909/how-to-shutdown-and-power-off-virtual-machines-over-ssh-on-esxi5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.on <vmid>
```

where vmid can be found with

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms
```